# PHP | Paypal Rest API | java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using the express checkout REST API for payments on Paypal. I successfully retreive my token using CURL in PHP. However the next part which actually makes the payment is not working.

**I get the following error:**

java.lang.NullPointerException (i beleive this error is from paypal?)

I have tried going through the code but i dont understand what i am doing wrong as it is all simple structure.

**My Code:**

```
$payment_result_json = array(
                       "intent" => "sale", 
                       "redirect_urls" => array("return_url" => "http://paypal/paypal_return.php", "cancel_url" => "http://paypal/paypal_cancel.php"),
                       "payer" => array("payment_method" => "paypal"),
                       "transactions" => array(

                            "amount" => array("amount" => array(
                                "total" => "1", "currency" => "USD", "details" => array(
                                    "subtotal" => "1", "shipping" => "0", "tax" => "1", "shipping_discount" => "0"
                                    )
                            )),

                            "item_list" => array("quantity" => "1", "name" => "Item 1", "price" => "1", "currency" => "USD", "description" => "item1 desc","tax" => "1"),
                            "description" => "Tutoring lesson"
                       ));

$post_headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $retreived_access_token");

$ch = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $post_headers);

while(empty($payment_result)){
    $payment_result = curl_exec($ch);
}

if(empty($payment_result)){
    print curl_error($ch);
}else{
    print $payment_result;
}

curl_close($ch);

$payment_result_json = json_decode($payment_result);

print_r($payment_result_json);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue Yesterday. I solved it adding this header:
`$post_headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $retreived_access_token", "Content-Type: application/json");`

Hope it helps